# Arc Length with Parametric Equations

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, parametric

After working with some parametric equations, I have arrived to the following integral that describes arc length.

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{9x^{12} + 10000x^8 - 1080x^6 + 32400}{10000x^8}}dx$$

Using by parts integration doesn't seem to work.

I seem to have lost the starting values for f(x) and g(x), but they were something along the lines of:

$$f(x)=x$$ and $$g(x)=\frac{x^3}{100}+\frac{6}{10x^3}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to see the originally given equations for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Even a minor typo could make a whole lot of difference when it comes to integration -- it can turn a simple problem into an impossible one. Wolfram Mathematica can't evaluate the integral in your question, and that's a bad sign.

Comment: Those are indeed the starting equations. I derived and squared g(x) again and arrived at (9x^12-1080^6+32400)/10000x^8, that plus derived and squared f(x), which is 1, adds a positive 10000x^8 to the numerator. Wolfram PRO claims it can solve it, but I don't have a license.
Made a little mistake not squaring the 100 in the denominator. Corrected the integral.

Comment: I tried both WolframAlpha Pro and Wolfram Mathematica 11.0 -- they can't do it...